# What are these Dragon Age: Inquisition Easter Eggs?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I found 2 'big' easter eggs so far while playing DA:I.

One is the golden chalice between some rocks in the Western Approach which you can't reach.

[image: golden chalice]

On the map it's [here](https://i.gyazo.com/10ef33127b10e158f62ba59d6f7913cd.png):

---

The second one is the big cheese in Crestwood

[image: cheese!]

[Map](https://i.gyazo.com/9d9e1120efaeaa64d28921ae0e41094c.png)

---

I've read that the cheese one is a common easter egg from Bioware but i don't understand them or what they reference. Can someone explain these?

Comment: In my edit i have removed your final paragraph, if people want their own Easter Eggs explained they should ask their own [question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and not post them as answers. if you want to know what all of the ester eggs are then you should reword your question do ask as such

Comment: For the one that downvoted my question, care to explain why? It has 900 views in 10 days and no one bothered to upvote it. and now 0 answers and someone downvotes it. I dont understand...

Comment: Take a look on ign http://www.ign.com/wikis/dragon-age-inquisition/Easter_Eggs_and_References here's a list of easter eggs and references or on wikia http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Easter_eggs_%28Inquisition%29

Comment: @DejaVu, if 900 views did not garnish a single upvote, it could be possible that users just dont think this is upvote worthy

Answer (score -1):

In Skyhold you can fall through the map and find a giant bunny in a top hat that plays music when you get close. There is an invisible guy that you can sometimes target through the wall in the basement in Skyhold, he's behind the big painting. He's supposed to ask you trivia but I've never been able to reach him. He's apparently a bit like Mai'q the Liar in the Elder Scrolls games, just an NP that shows up and mocks the game a bit.

The first one you posted, the holy grail one, is just that, a reference to the holy grail. It's not reachable.

Sometimes these are just in-jokes, I imagine with the cheese it sort of started that way and took on a life of its own.

Comment: The trivia question guy can be visible and reachable, he turns up repeatedly in several hard-to-reach places in Skyhold. If he's invisible behind a wall, it's probably a bug.